# How to get the id of the attribute from an element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i wrote this mini jquery snippet, but i want to get the id of the li element so i can post this data to an ajax call this is my script

```
 $('#list li a').on('click', function(e) {

        var id = ? //need to get li id
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "unfollow.php",
        data: id,
        success: function(){
            $(this).parent().hide();
        $('.updateNumber').html(function(){
            return parseInt($(this).text(),10)+1;
          });
        }
         });
       });
    });
```

this is an example html list:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li id="list_1" class="list"><a href="">hide</a></li>
</ul>
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use plain javascript (no need for the extra calls to jQuery)

```
var id = this.parentNode.id
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/rL29r/

EDIT - to get just the number

```
var id = this.parentNode.id.replace('list_', '')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rL29r/2/

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i don't what it to hold list_1 only the number 1, sorry i didnt clarify!!

Comment: var id_number = this.parentNode.id.match(/\d+/)[0]

Comment: @MidnightCoder then use `this.parentNode.id.replace('list_', '');` http://jsfiddle.net/rL29r/2/

Answer (score 3):

```
 $('#list li a').on('click', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).parent("li").attr("id");
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "unfollow.php",
    data: id,
    success: function(){
        $(this).parent().hide();
    $('.updateNumber').html(function(){
        return parseInt($(this).text(),10)+1;
      });
    }
     });
   });
});
```

- see http://api.jquery.com/attr/
- see http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: he wants the id of the li, the selector is on the "a" so i would rather say: var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");

Comment: how can i get remove the list_ from the list_1, i only want it to display the number 1! sorry i didnt clarify!!!

Comment: you can do `.replace()` on the id.

Comment: just replace it with the replace function of javascript. the var id is a string so you can make id = id.replace("list_",""). -> http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/string.htm#replace @MidnightCoder

Answer (score 1):

Since the `<a>` elements you're matching are descendants of `<li>` elements, and you seem to be wanting the `id` of the ancestor `<li>` element, you can use the [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method:

```
var id = $(this).closest("li").attr("id");
```

Comment: in this case i think you could avoid the overhead of making all those calls with `this.parentNode.id`

Comment: @Nicola, you're right since the `<a>` element is a direct children of the `<li>` element in the questioner markup. But the selector he uses is `#list li a` and not `#list li > a`, though, so I used `closest()` to be on the safe side :)

Comment: Yes to be on the safe side you are absolutely right, it's a performance vs portabilty issue! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
id = this.parentNode.id;
```

This is at least 8 times faster than the jQuery equivalent. Don't use jQuery for something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dm3uQ/1/) on jsFiddle.net. You will need to use `.parent()` with `$(this)`.

HTML

```
<ul id="list">
  <li id="list_1">
    <a href="#">Test Anchor One</a>
  </li>
  <li id="list_2">
    <a  href="#">Test Anchor Two</a>
  </li>
</ul>​
```

JavaScript

```
$('#list li a').on('click', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).parent().attr("id").replace("list_", "");
   alert(id);
});​
```

This will give `1` or `2` as `id`.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

For the number of `list_n` use

```
var id = this.parentNode.id;
var number = id.substring(5);
```